# Laptop charges normally on windows but inconsistently on Ubuntu

Tags: power-management, battery

I recently installed Ubuntu on my HP Envy laptop and for whatever reason, it charges completely normally on Windows but when I switch to Ubuntu, the charging becomes very sporadic. It randomly starts and stops charging and I can't seem to notice a pattern. Is there any way to fix it and make the charging normal? I know it can't be a hardware issue because it charges fine on Windows. Thanks